# Adding to an array with an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, promise

assume I have an array of files, file_urls, I want to parse through and add the results to a result array:

```
var requestImageSize = require('request-image-size');

function parse_file(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        /*this is an asynchronous function from an external library,
         it returns attributes about the file such as its size and dimensions
        */
        requestImageSize(file).then(function(result) { 
            resolve(result);            
        }
        .catch(function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });   
    })
}
var results = [];
var promise;

//assume file_urls is already populated with strings of urls to files
file_urls.each(function(index, elem) {
    //if it's the last element then return the promise so we can return the final results at the end
    if (index == file_urls.length-1) {
        promise = parse_file(this);
    }
    //otherwise process the promise
    else {
        parse_file(this).then(function(result) {
            results.push(result);
        }
    }
});

//add the final element and return the final results
promise.then(function(result) { 
    results.push(result);
    return result;
});
```

Since parse_file returns a promise and I'm iterating through many promises, how do I ensure that the results array has the correct number (and possibly order) of elements?

so far in my project it is returning an erratic number of elements, what should I do differently?

Comment: The problem here is that it's possible that the last promise can return before the first promise.  As stated below,  you may use `Promise.All`Using this has causes me compatibility issues before. As well as using promises in general.  Another option would be to use callbacks. If the callback has been called x number of times  (x representing the array length), then return the necessary values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom you're looking for is `Promise.all` combined with `.map`:

```
Promise.all(file_urls.map(parse_file)).then(results => ...)
```

`Promise.all` ensures you get all results in correct order, it doesn't enforce any particular order of execution though.